# Match multiple conditions in powershell regular expression

Tags: regex, powershell

In powershell I need to iterate through and return a list of all the unique first element (before the first `::`) that start with `puppet_` eg. `puppet_customer` and `puppet_edcs`. If possible exclude some from the puppet_ list like `puppet_enterprise` and `puppet_metrics_collector` and `puppet_agent`

```
chocolatey
pe_install::install
pe_postgresql::lib::devel
profile::agent_config
puppet_agent::install::remove_packages
puppet_customer::customer_shared::alerts
puppet_customer::email_shared::email
puppet_edcs::claims::grt_api
puppet_enterprise::certs::puppetdb_whitelist
puppet_ets::windows::defaults::audit_policy
puppet_metrics_collector
puppet_policyservicing::owbinet::file_cluster
puppet_printserver::print
puppet_product::avrt::avrt
puppet_quoting::aqw_dca::aqw
puppet_testing::ourtestfile
puppet_webpresence::lifelanes_webapp
role::customer::customer_shared
```

This is the list I expect it to return

```
puppet_customer
puppet_edcs
puppet_ets
puppet_policyservicing
puppet_printserver
puppet_product
puppet_quoting
puppet_webpresence
```

---

```
$invoke.name | Select-String -Pattern ^puppet_.*\:\:'(\w+)'\:\:'(\w+)'$ | 
    foreach {$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value} | Sort-Object | Unique`
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
'^puppet_(?!enterprise|metrics_collector|agent|testing)\w+'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Uhnet8/1). It will match `puppet_` at the start of a line that is not immediately followed with `enterprise`, `metrics_collector`, `agent`, `testing` and then 1 or more word chars will be consumed:

[image]

Note you need to access the *whole match value*, not a capturing group value, i.e. `$_.Matches.Value` in this case.

If you want to avoid matching only in case the "stop" words are followed with `::` adjust the pattern like

```
^puppet_(?!(?:enterprise|metrics_collector|agent|testing)::)\w+
           ^^^                                          ^^^
```

See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Uhnet8/2).

Answer (score 1):

[Wiktor Stribiżew's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55878127/45375) solves your problem by providing the requisite regex, which involves a negative-lookahead assertion (`(?!...)`).

This answer shows you an alternative that avoids the complexity of the required regex.

---

PowerShell has many flexible cmdlets and string operators, and while chaining them via the pipeline may not be the fastest option, it allows for conceptually simple solutions:

```
$invoke.name -split '::' -like 'puppet_*' |
  Sort-Object -Unique |
   Where { $_ -notin 'puppet_enterprise', 'puppet_metrics_collector', 'puppet_agent'}
```

<sup>Note: The above assumes that on any given line, `::`-separated tokens that start with `puppet_` occur only as the *first* token on that line, if any; if that assumption doesn't hold, more work is needed.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$yourlist | where {$_ -like "puppet_*" -and $_ -notlike '*puppet_enterprise*'  -and $_ -notlike '*puppet_metrics_collector*' -and $_ -notlike '*puppet_agent*' } | 
    %{($_ -split "::")[0]} | sort -Unique
```

Answer (score -1):

What about:

`puppet_(?!enterprise|metrics_collector|agent|testing)(.*?)::`

https://regex101.com/r/gQ1yF5/2